# Entity framework ошибка Invalid column name при доступе к таблице

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте.

Есть 3 связанных сущности

```
public class Station : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Ecp код станции")]
    public int EcpCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название станции")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RailwayStation> RailwayStations { get; set; }                            //Многие ко многим с RailwayStation (для вывода всех станций по вокзалу) 
} 


public class RegulatorySchedule : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string NumberOfTrain { get; set; }                   //Номер поезда в расписании

    public virtual Station DispatchStation { get; set; }        //Станция отправления

    public virtual Station DestinationStation { get; set; }     //Станция назначения

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? ArrivalTime { get; set; }                  //Время прибытия поезда на станцию

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? DepartureTime { get; set; }                //Время отправления поезда со станции


    #region FK

    [Required]
    public RailwayStation RailwayStation { get; set; }                           //Обязательно относится к вокзалу            

    #endregion
}


public class RailwayStation : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название станции")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Station> Stations { get; set; }                             // многие ко многим с Station. (список возможных станций этого вокзала)

    public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatorySchedules { get; set; }       // один ко многим с RegulatorySchedules. (одна запись в расписании принаджежит только 1 вокзалу)
}
```

Строка подключения

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CisDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\CisDbContextTest999.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

При обращении к таблице *RegulatorySchedule* на чтение всех элементов. (База только что создана, таблицы пустые). Возникает исключение
 `Message = "Invalid column name 'DestinationStation_Id'."`

Скорее всего у меня 2 связи с типом *Station (DispatchStation* и *DestinationStation)* и *entity* путается тут. Подскажите пожалуйста, где не правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
public class RegulatorySchedule
{
    public int DispatchID { get; set; }

    public int DestinationID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DispatchID")]
    public virtual Station DispatchStation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DestinationID")]
    public virtual Station DestinationStation { get; set; }

}
```

См. тж. [тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604432/)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Получается при связе 1 к 1 в таблицу Stations ничего добавлять не надо?

Comment: @Aldmi Верно. Подробнее можно почитать тут: http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-entity-framework-03-code-first-conventions

Comment: Спасибо еще раз.