# Ошибка сервера в приложении SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mvc

Проблема следующая - пишу приложение используя ASP.NET MVC 5. Создал БД в entity fraemwork пробую подключиться к ней, получаю ошибку: Ошибка сервера в приложении SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'RequestType_Id'. Такого имени колонки нет в моей БД.
В HomeController создаю метод:

```
public ActionResult RequestProcessing()
    {   
        return View(db.RequestProcessings.ToList());
    }
```

Для получения списка заявок.

Представление для RequestProcessing

```
@model IEnumerable<ITSMForSchool.Models.RequestProcessing>
@using ITSMForSchool.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RequestProcessing";
}

<h2>RequestProcessing</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeadLine)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpecialistId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StatusId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TypeId)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeadLine)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SpecialistId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestType.TypeName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Сам класс RequestProcessings

```
public class RequestProcessing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }

    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    public int? SpecialistId { get; set; }
    public Specialist Specialist { get; set; }
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public int? TypeId { get; set; }
    public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
}
```

Класс RequestType

```
public class RequestType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int TimeComplete { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestProcessing> RequestProcessings { get; set; }
    public RequestType()
    {
        RequestProcessings = new List<RequestProcessing>();
    }
}
```

Класс контекста данных

```
 public class ITSMContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Specialist> Specialists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RequestProcessing> RequestProcessings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RequestType> RequestTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TypeAsset> TypesAsset { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(c => c.Specialists)
            .WithMany(s => s.Roles)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("RolesId")
            .MapRightKey("SpecialistId")
            .ToTable("ListSpecialistRoles"));
    }
}
```

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, можете помочь, подсказать почему запрашивается название сущности, которая не существует? 
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Отсутствует связь один ко многим: protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RequestProcessing>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.RequestType )
            .WithMany(d => d.RequestProcessings);
    }

Comment: Yaroslav, попробовал добавить данный код, но ошибка сохранилась.

Comment: добавьте еще свойство к RequestProcessing: public int RequestTypeId { get; set; } под public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }

Comment: При добавлении этой строки ошибка меняется с "Invalid column name 'RequestType_Id'" на "Invalid column name 'RequestTypeId'"

Comment: Ошибку поправил применив рекомендации из темы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607171/entity-framework-ошибка-invalid-column-name-при-доступе-к-таблице?rq=1

Comment: по факту решение такое же, только на атрибутах построено, а я приводил пример Fluent API

Comment: может вы что то не так сделали

Comment: @Yaroslav может и я что-то сделал неправильно. Я только начинаю изучать данную технологию, поэтому делаю много ошибок.